# Can you please verify I am writing this function correctly

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

my function

```
function verify_range()
    {
        if((sale_price.value)<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> document.getElementById('PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales1')
        {
            document.getElementById('PS_FORM/MARKET_DATA/NeighborhoodSales1').value = adjusted_value.value;
        }
    }
```

The function is supposed to look at data from 2 fields.  If data field 2 which is sale_price.value is less than neighborhoodsales1 then neighborhoodsales is the sale_price.

This is in html but reads off of xsl and html.  I am unsure of how to do less than because i tried < and an error pops up when i use that symbol.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't mix XSLT and javascript like that. Neither language understands the other's syntax.

As well, even if you remove the XSL stuff, your JS is still fundamentally broken

Comment: Are you running this through an XSLT engine before outputting the HTML?  If so, why would you need the XSLT value-of to put the less-than operator in there -- why not just type in the less-than symbol?

Comment: yes we code through an xml editor engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function is in the middle of some XSLT then `<` is a special character and will be considered as tag start. Although it could be prevented using this:

```
<![CDATA[
    function verify_range()
    ... // the rest of it
]]>
```

With this you say that no XML parsing should be performed with this text and you can use `<` in the function in normal way.

Comment: so with this tagging i can eliminate the xsl and use <?

Comment: Exactly! Within this CDATA code `<` will not be considered as special character.

Answer (score 0):

a small work around...

instead of doing : `if ( a < b )` you could do `if ( a - b < 0 )` that way you wont need to use the "<" char inside the xsl tag, but i guess that you'd also need to use CDATA for the javascript code..

Hope this helps